# JQuery browser resize initiating function

Tags: jquery, function, resize

I have the below function which works as expected on document ready but on resize it doesn't register the size change and executes the alert for the size before the resize.  Ive added the `menuInitialized` as a flag to try and combat the issue but now it initializes multiple times.  For example it will alert "Small", "Large", "small"  If I resize the browser multiple times.

```
var menuInitialized = false;

function doMenu() {
    var left = $('.c_left').height();
    var right = $('.c_right').height();
    if (left > right) {
        $('.c_right').css('height', left + 'px');
    }
    $(".c_left, .top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .header_image, .c_footer, .copyright, .accepts, .myaccount, .header_logo").removeAttr('style');
    var $menu = $(".c_left");
    var width = $(window).width();
    var status = 'closed';
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 550) {
        if (!menuInitialized) {
            $('.icon-menu-2').on('click', function(event) {
                alert('small');
                if (status === 'closed') {
                    $menu.animate({
                        width: 185,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                        marginLeft: 185,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".myaccount").animate({
                        marginRight: -185,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    return status = 'open';
                } else if (status === 'open') {
                    $menu.animate({
                        width: 0,
                        marginLeft: -185,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount,.c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".myaccount").animate({
                        marginRight: 0,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    return status = 'closed';
                }
            });
            menuInitialized = true;
        }

    } else if ((width < 800) && (width > 550)) {
        if (menuInitialized) {
             $('.icon-menu-2').on('click', function(event) {
                alert('large');
                if (status === 'closed') {
                    $menu.animate({
                        width: 185,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .header_image, .c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                        marginLeft: 185,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".myaccount, .header_logo").animate({
                        marginRight: -185,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    return status = 'open';
                } else if (status === 'open') {
                    $menu.animate({
                        width: 0,
                        marginLeft: -185,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .header_image,.c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    $(".myaccount, .header_logo").animate({
                        marginRight: 0,
                        display: 'toggle'
                    }, 'fast');
                    return status = 'closed';
                }
            });
            menuInitialized = false;
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(doMenu);
$(window).resize(doMenu);
```

Comment: Where does the variable `width` come from? You need to update `width` on resize!

Comment: Also, it will only fire once, as the if condition will fail on anything but the first time the user resizes.

Comment: Does `menuInitialized` ever get set to `false` again? Right now, the code inside that `if (!menuInitialized)` block can only run once, ever, because `!menuInitialized` stops being true once you enter the block.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to do this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3exZB/) ??

Comment: Yes thats exactly it @adeneo.  Thanks

Comment: oh actually @adeneo, when I use with with all my code and not the simplified version above, I run into the same issues.  It appears to alert multiple times instead of just the once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive needed to unbind the click function  ie: `$('.icon-menu').unbind('click');`

Answer (score 0):

Put all your js/jquery in the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(

    // Init
    var menuInitialized = false;
    doMenu();

    // Resize event
    $(window).resize(doMenu);

    // doMenu function
    function doMenu() {

        if (!menuInitialized) {
            menuInitialized = true;

            if (width < 550) {
                alert('small')
            } else if ((width < 800) && (width > 550)) {
               alert('large')
            }
        }
    }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you're not updating the value of `width`.

So inside the function you should get the new width of the object

```
function doMenu() {
    width = some_value // Get the width of the desired object

    // Your code here...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I had forgot to add that to this example, but my code does have a value for width.  I have amended the code above.

Comment: OK, well then look at the comment above about `menuInitialized`; it never is set to `false` once it's been set to `true`.